# I want the program read int string double

Tags: c++

I want a program to read from my txt file like this `int string double`. I think we should use array.

This is my txt file:

1   Nasi Ayam Penyet            8.00

2   Nasi Goreng Pattaya          9.00

3  Nasi Goreng Tom Yam           10.00

4   Nasi Goreng Kampung         8.00

5    Nasi Ayam BBQ       9.00

```
enter code here`
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string name[25];
string str[25];
string line; 
int first_number[25];
double num[25];
int i = 0; // to increment the variables above
ifstream infile;
infile.open("list.txt");
if(infile.is_open()) 
{
while(!infile.eof())
{
infile >> first_number[i];
getline(infile,line);
for(int k = 0; k < line.length(); k++)
 {
     if(isdigit(line[k]) || ispunct(line[k]))
         str[i] += line[k];
     else
         name[i] += line[k];
 }
num[i] = strtol(str[i].c_str(), NULL, 0);
cout << first_number[i] <<name[i];
cout <<setprecision(2)<< num[i] << endl;
i++;
 }
   infile.close();
 }
 }
```

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/496/file-i-o#t=201705070128316664481)

Comment: i want a sports-car. What have you tried and where are you stuck? S.O is not a 'code it for me' service.

Comment: sorry this is my code i think there is somthing wrong i am still new in c++

Comment: Are the numbers 1 to 6 in your text file?

Comment: yes the number 1-6 in txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string name[25];
string str[25];
string line; 
int first_number[25];
double num[25];
int i = 0; // to increment the variables above

ifstream infile;
infile.open(filename);
if(infile.is_open())
{
    while(infile >> first_number[i])
    {
        getline(infile,line);
   for(int k = 0; k < line.length(); k++)
     {
         if(isdigit(line[k]) || ispunct(line[k]))
             str[i] += line[k];
         else
             name[i] += line[k];
     }
   num[i] = strtol(str[i].c_str(), NULL, 0);
   i++;
 }
       infile.close();
 }
```

for strtol use cstdlib if something doesn't make sense leave a comment I will try my best to explain it.